# Create sub groups with the position of element from a list

Tags: python, sublist

I have to create sub groups with the position of element from a list based on the value of elements which means sub groups will contain the same elements from the list.

However, the size of the sub group will depend on the value of the group.

Example: `A = [2,1,1,2,1]` will create `[0, 3] [1] [2] [4]`

I have written the below code. However, all the test cases are not getting passed.

I am not getting correct output if A = [2,1,2,1,2,2]. For my case I am getting:

```
0 2
4 5
1
3
```

However, expectation is:

```
0 2
1
3
4 5
```

Below is my code:

```
A = [2,1,1,2,1]
uniqueCounts = []
for x in A:
    if x not in uniqueCounts:
        uniqueCounts.append(x)

for i in range(len(uniqueCounts)):
    n = uniqueCounts[i]
    p = [i for i,x in enumerate(A) if x == n]

    if(len(p)==1):
        print(*p)
    else:
        q = int(len(p)/n)
        count = 0
        c = 0
        while count < q:
            print(*p[c:n+c])
            c = c + n
            count = count + 1
```

Comment: Did you rather mean `[0, 3, 1, 2, 4]`?

Comment: I am not getting correct output if A = [2,1,2,1,2,2]. For my case I am getting: 0 2, 4 5, 1, 3. However, expectation is: 0 2, 1, 3, 4 5

Answer (score 0):

You should use numpy and the function `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np

A = [2,1,1,2,1]
A = np.asarray(A)
ID = np.where(A == 2)[0]
```

Output:

```
ID = array([0, 3], dtype=int64)
```

You can then work with this array to transform it into list, count the number of element using the `shape` or `len`... and so on.

To get back to your code:

```
A = [2,1,1,2,1]
uniqueCounts = list(set(A))
```

`set` is returning a set without duplicates. converting it to list gives you the uniqueCounts directly.

Conclusion:

```
A = [2,1,1,2,1]
uniqueCounts = list(set(A))
A = np.asarray(A)

subgroup = list()

for elt in uniqueCounts:
    subgroup.append(tuple(np.where(A == elt)[0]))
```

Some work is still needed to get the desired output, I'll let that to you :)

Answer (score 0):

First sort the list `A` with only unique elements. without losing the order. Then find all the indices for the elements in the sorted list from the original list

```
A = [2,1,1,2,1]
sortedA = sorted(set(A), key=A.index)
# [2, 1]

[[i for i,x in enumerate(A) if x==e] for e in sortedA]
# [[0, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: The 2nd sublist contains [1,2,4]. However, it should be three individual sub list like [1] [2] [4]

Comment: I assume it was a mistake from OP. He mentioned `create sub groups with the position of element from a list based on the value of elements`. So either the result has to be `[0 3 1 2 4]` or `[[0,3], [1,2,4]]`